# RxJava: window/buffer overload questions, incompatibility with Rx.NET?

Tags: rx-java

I'm reading http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#SequencesOfCoincidence and found the following part there about the `window` operator:

"The first of these complex overloads allows us to control when windows should close. **The windowClosingSelector function is called each time a window is created.** Windows are created on subscription and immediately after a window closes; windows close when the sequence from the windowClosingSelector produces a value. The value is disregarded so it doesn't matter what type the sequence values are; in fact **you can just complete the sequence from windowClosingSelector to close the window instead**."

This seems to be different than the `public final <TClosing> Observable<Observable<T>> window(Func0<? extends Observable<? extends TClosing>> closingSelector)` method documentation and behavior. My tests show that the `Func0` to produce the closing observable is only ever called once, neither does completing this observable work as described above - only one window is ever created. This method actually works the same as the `public final <U> Observable<Observable<T>> window(Observable<U> boundary)` method, with the exception that the boundary is passed directly and not with a function. Judging by the source code, the latter/simpler method just calls into the former/more complicated one by wrapping the passed boundary into a Func0 which just returns it.

Questions:

1. It would seem the behavior of RxJava's `public final <TClosing> Observable<Observable<T>> window(Func0<? extends Observable<? extends TClosing>> closingSelector)` might be wrong, unless the book is wrong or the newer versions of Rx.NET, with which RxJava is compatible, changed. Is this a deliberate incompatibility between Rx.NET and RxJava?
2. Should the incompatibility be the correct behavior, why does RxJava have 2 `window` overloads which actually do pretty much the same? I don't see any clear advantage of having the overload with a function creating the window closing observable if it doesn't take any arguments and is ever going to be called once. Ok, it makes creation of the observable lazy, but I think this could be achieved with the `defer` method.
3. What adds to the confusion is the fact that the marble diagrams for the two overloads are slightly different (the arrows are). Maybe I just don't understand the real difference there?

The same two overloads exist for the `buffer` method.

Here is some code, more or less a port from the mentioned article. Each line of input closes the current and opens a new window, unless it is 'q' (case insensitive), in which case the whole thing finishes.

```java
Observable<Long> source = Observable.interval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
PublishSubject<Object> closer = PublishSubject.create();

Subscription s = source
        .window(() -> {
            System.out.println("!!! creating window closer");
            return closer;
        })
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Observable<Long>>() {

            private int idx = 0;

            @Override
            public void onNext(Observable<Long> window) {
                ++idx;
                System.out.printf("+++ starting new window%n");
                String windowName = "window " + idx;
                window.subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                        System.out.printf("%s -> %d%n", windowName, aLong);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // nothing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        System.out.printf("--- %s completed%n", windowName);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("completed");
            }
        });

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
do {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    closer.onNext(input);
    //closer.onCompleted();
} while (!"q".equalsIgnoreCase(input));
s.unsubscribe();
```

Replacing the `closer.onNext()` line with `closer.onCompleted()` breaks the application - only one window is ever created.

Comment: This looks like a discrepancy between the two implementation. When RxJava window was implemented, the exact behavior of the .NET version was still unclear. You should bring up this issue on the RxJava github page. Regardless, completing the PublishSubject might not be a good idea because it will just complete the main sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I brought the question up at the Github page and it has been fixed: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3053.